# PHP error- Undefined property: stdClass - How to fix w/ a bunch of objects?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an  Undefined property: stdClass::$company error.

This fixes it

```
   if(isset($exp->company){
       /stuff here
      }
```

but I have a bunch of objects so I would have to that for each. Is there a cleaner way to fix this?

here is the entire thing

```
   function test() {
 foreach($_POST['experience'] as $experience)
    {

       $exp=(object)$experience;

    }

             }
```

Comment: Use `isset` for the array containing those objects

Comment: We need to know what is generating `$exp` first.

Comment: That's not really a fix, you're just getting rid of the error. The root problem is still there, which is that you have objects that are missing properties.

Comment: Ther is no object missing properties, simply they lack of them. The error shows that the object is an instance of stdClass so you better define the properties you may need when create/populate those standard objects.

Answer (score 1):

A class is like the building plan of a house. A object is a house build according to the plan.

By using a `stdClass` this is what happening: You ask: "I want to use the bathroom", not knowing if there is a bathroom present. When there is no bathroom, you are in deep trouble (shit).

Try to make a building plan, e.g. do not use a `stdClass` but write your own class. Then you know what properties and methods are present at forehand.

Otherwise you have to ask with every move you make: is that room present, e.g. `if(isset($exp->company)`

Comment: +1 [cool story bro.](http://i766.photobucket.com/albums/xx304/thebitchlizard/Funny%20pics/Cool-Dog-Hey-Cool-story-bro41.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague - but this might help

```
foreach ($exp as $object)
{
   // do stuf to $object
}
```

Comment: Geez I don't know why I didn't think to do a nested foreach. Thanks so much!

Comment: actually that doesn't work it just strips away the object so I no longer can do something like $object->company, etc.

Comment: Also In relation to my question I don't want to keep typing if(isset($exp->x)) for every single object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a clean way. You must to go to the roots: where do you create those stdClass instances? Go there and define as `null` every property you may need, despite you populate only some of those properties.

If you did not instantiate those stdClass objects and you stored them in `$_SESSION`, you must to `include` your custom classes before `session_start`.